# Accessing local domain from android

Tags: ubuntu, server, moodle

I am trying to access my .local moodle domain from an android device, the server is set up on ubuntu 20.0.4. I am facing this problem only on android devices I tried it on desktop and iphone and it worked perfectly fine. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using same wifi/network ? are you trying to access it using private ip of you host or localhost or public ip ? Kindly provide more details to short the problem.

Comment: yes I am connected to the same network, the server was set up on apache2 where I set the domain to .local inside apache2/enabled-sites/moodle.conf

Comment: I tried to change the domain name from .local to .home, I change it in /etc/apache2/site-available/moodle.conf And /etc/hosts And in moodle/config.php, reboot apache, pinging moodle.home gives "name or server not found" but pinging to .local works perfectly fine

Comment: It seems you are able to reach the system but host name resolution is not getting correct values. Kindly check if you have set any proxy parameter for moodle to be resolved or try with different browser in mobile like firefox or brave.